# Is it possible to rewrite this SQL query without nesting in the FROM

Tags: sql, nested

```
SELECT id, 
       COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT id, 
                  value
  FROM tablename 
  WHERE column  = 'some filter'
)
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I tried using a self join but having trouble getting the output to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT value)
FROM tablename 
WHERE column  = 'some filter'
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) > 1;
```

Comment: Note to the OP. Will work, though I recommend not to use numbers in `GROUP BY`. It's simpler to use the columns/expressions.

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . I go back and forth on that.  I find it incredibly convenient when I am investigating data and need to keep changing the aggregation conditions.

Comment: Excellent.  That worked.   Interesting the subquery version runs slightly faster.  My guess would have been taking out the subquery should have improved the performance.

Comment: @addiwei . . . That depends on the database.  In some databases, your subquery form is vastly preferred (because `select distinct` will use parallel processors but `count(distinct)` does not in those databases).  In some databases, your version can make more efficient use of indexes.